# Several YouTube channels on one e-mail account

Tags: youtube

Can we create two or more YouTube channels on one e-mail account and also can we connect both of them with one bank account? Actually I am a videos creator of both education and tourism. So, I want to have both of the channels separate from one another, in order to avoid users confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we create two or more YouTube channels on one e-mail account..

Short answer yes.
YouTube gives you the option to **manage up to 200 channels from one Google Account**.

There is a "trick" though you need to be aware of.
You need to **have them connected to separate Google+ pages**.
This means that using one and the same Google (e-mail) Account you create different Google+ pages (now through Google Business) and link/connect each one of those pages to a different YouTube channel.
**Be aware though**: linking a YouTube channel to a Google+ Page, your YouTube channel and the Page connected to, cannot be unlinked.

> ...can we connect both of them with one bank account

Actually in order to monetize your YouTube channels you have to link them to an AdSense account. So in reality you connect all of them to just one bank account.

> From the [Google Help Pages](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72866):
>   If you want to monetize multiple YouTube channels, you don't need to open a new AdSense account. You can monetise more than one YouTube channel with the same AdSense account. Just follow the instructions below to add the channels to an approved AdSense account.